# initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate return null when the year is less than 2000

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have this code below that storage my date from date picker:

```
uint64_t offset = (uint64_t)[[self.dataPicker date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
// store this 64-bit unsigned integer.

NSLog(@"Offset -> %llu",offset);
```

To convert date format again I use the following command:

```
NSDate *data = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:offset];
NSLog(@"Before -> %@",data);
```

But this code has a problem, the command `initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` always return null when I select a smaller year than 2000 (1999,1998,1997 ...), but the `offset` is still to store a value.

What is happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that could be a hint: for `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, the doc says: "This property’s value is negative if the date object is earlier than the system’s absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001)." And `uint64_t` seems quite unsigned, and so may have issue negative values. I'd recommend to save as `NSTimeInterval` (which holds `double` primitive).

Comment: Does it really return null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these facts:

- The reference date is Jan 1, 2001.
- All time interval values before that date are negative.
- You are using the type `uint64_t` which can never be negative.

There is a dedicated type `NSTimeInterval` (aka double).